# PHP: file missing after upload

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

After an upload, the `print_r` output for the image field is as follows

```
Array 
(
    [name] => foo.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php63EvNo
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 19115 
)
```

Since the `error` is zero, and the `filesize` is non-zero I assume that the upload is successful.

A subsequent call to move uploaded file fails: `move_uploaded_file(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Upon inspecting `/tmp`, the file named in `tmp_name` is not there.

What causes this behaviour/ how to rectify?

Thanks!

---

Extra info:
LAMP stack, running PHP5, CakePHP 2.0

The form:
php/ cake code:

```
echo $form->input('Foo.image', array('type' => 'file'));
```

html that is rendered:

```
<input type="file" name="data[Foo][image]"  id="FooImage"/>
```

Comment: try searching for the file. you might have misplaced it OR check folder permissions.

Comment: Can we see the `move_uploaded_file` part?

Comment: @Joseph - folder permission were indeed the issue - `chmod -R 777` on the intended location fixed the problem.
If you answer this question, I'll give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary uploaded files in `/tmp` are deleted at the end of the request -- they are not kept around long-term. You have to use `move_uploaded_file` during the request that received an upload if you care about the file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a permissions issue. Also consider using the cakePHP folder variables. The upload component I have looks like this:

```
$file = $this->request->data['Client']['image'];

$filename = $file['tmp_name'];
$filePath = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS . $file['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $filePath))
    return '/files/'.$file['name']; // saves location of uploaded file
```